# My code wont work, is there some logical error here?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Can someone help me, Im trying to make a banking program and when i try to login and enter the correct details, it still says "notok". I put in some values for testing purposes and it just wont work and it would always print notok. Please help

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import random 


def checklog(ac,pin):
    if (ac==1) and (pin==2):
        print("ok")
    else:
        print("notok")



def exitwin(master):

    master.destroy()



def acc_no(master):

    acc_no.acc = random.randrange(1000000000,9999999999)

    messagebox.showinfo("Account Number", acc_no.acc)
    return

def openac():

    op = tk.Tk()
    op.title("Open a account")
    op.minsize(500,500)
    op.configure(bg='gray90')

    l1 = tk.Label(op, text="Full Name")
    l1.grid(row=0, column=2)

    openac.name = tk.Entry(op)
    openac.name.grid(row=0, column=3)

    l2 = tk.Label(op, text="Enter Starting Deposit")
    l2.grid(row=1, column=2)

    openac.fun = tk.Entry(op)
    openac.fun.grid(row=1, column=3)

    l3 = tk.Label(op, text="Enter your pin")
    l3.grid(row=2, column=2)

    openac.pin = tk.Entry(op, show="*")
    openac.pin.grid(row=2, column=3)

    sub = tk.Button(op, text="Submit", command=lambda: [acc_no(op), login(), exitwin(op)])

    sub.grid(row=3, column=1)

    op.bind("<Return>", lambda x:[dep(op, e1.get(),e2.get(), e3.get()), acc_no(op), login(op, e1.get(), e2.get(), e3.get()), exitwin(op)])


    return



def login():

    log = tk.Tk()
    log.title("Login")
    log.minsize(500,500)

    l1 = tk.Label(log, text="Enter your account number")
    l1.grid(row=0, column=0)

    e1 = tk.Entry(log)
    e1.grid(row=0, column=1)

    l2 = tk.Label(log, text="Enter your pin")
    l2.grid(row=1, column=0)

    e2 = tk.Entry(log)
    e2.grid(row=1, column=1)

    sub = tk.Button(log, text="Sumbit", command=lambda: checklog(e1.get(), e2.get()))
    sub.grid(row=1, column=2)

    return

    log.mainloop()




def dep(master, name, fund, pin):
    x=0



def draw():
    x=0



def mainmenu():

    mm = tk.Tk()
    mm.title("Bank")
    mm.minsize(400,400)
    mm.configure(bg='gray70')


    l1 = tk.Label(mm, text="HELLO")
    l1.config(font=("Courier", "25"))
    l1.grid(row=0)

    b1 = tk.Button(mm, text="Sign Up", command=openac)
    b1.grid(row=2)

    b2 = tk.Button(mm, text="Log In", command=lambda: login(mm))
    b2.grid(row=3)

    mm.mainloop()

mainmenu()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're checking if the .get()'s of your text boxes are equal to an integer, but you have not converted them into an integer, they are a string by default.

```
def checklog(ac, pin):
    if ac == "1" and pin == "2":
        print("ok")
    else:
        print("not ok")
```

Best practice dictates that you convert the value to an integer yourself and throw an error when it cannot be converted. Something that tells the user their account number or pin failed validation as it is not a number.

Answer (score 1):

The values that you pass to `checklog` come from calling `.get` on a `tk.Entry`, which produces a string (it must do this, because you could type whatever text you like, not just ones that look like numbers). The comparison `ac==1` fails because `ac` is a string. You must convert the value yourself, and handle the case when a non-number is typed.

This is not really a Tkinter question; it's the same problem that beginners have all the time with `input()`.

Comment: Yeah, thanks a lot. I'm just starting out with python and tkinter as a student, that's why i get confused